# How to find same values in dictionary and assign a new item with averaging of duplicate values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a text file with movie details,structure like this;

| ID | Rating | Title | Genre |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 4.5 | Amelie (Fabuleux destin d'Amélie Poulain, Le) (2001) | Comedy|Romance|Thriller |
| 1 | 3.0 | Die Hard (1988) | Action|Crime|Thriller |
| 2 | 4.0 | Star Wars: Episode VI - Return of the Jedi (1983) | Action|Adventure|Sci-Fi |
| 3 | 3.5 | Fugitive, The (1993) | Thriller |
| 4 | 4.5 | Fugitive, The (1993) | Thriller |
| 5 | 2.5 | Amelie (Fabuleux destin d'Amélie Poulain, Le) (2001) | Comedy|Romance|Thriller |

I want to find the same movies and save them as a new item by taking the average rating of the movies I found.

For example;
Fugitive is duplicated on the list. Average rating: 4.0

```
{'580': ['4.0', 'Jurassic Park (1993)', ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Sci-Fi', 'Thriller']], 
 '264': ['4.0', 'Mask, The (1994)', ['Action', 'Comedy', 'Crime', 'Fantasy', 'Thriller']], 
 '370': ['4.5', "Amelie) (2001)", ['Comedy', 'Romance', 'Thriller']], 
 '312': ['3.0', 'Die Hard (1988)', ['Action', 'Crime', 'Thriller']], 
 '166': ['3.5', 'Fugitive, The (1993)', ['Thriller']], 
 '195': ['4.5', 'Fugitive, The (1993)', ['Thriller']]}
```

I have saved each line in the file as an item in the dictionary. How can I find and average the same items? Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0):

Read the file with pandas, then group by 'Title' and compute the mean of the column 'Rating'